# About Taylor's Theorem in "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak

Tags: calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

I am reading "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak.

He derived the following proposition on p.423:

> If $f^{n+1}$ is continuous on $[a, x]$, then the following equality holds:  $$f(x) = f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f^{''}(a)}{2}(x-a)^2+\cdots+\frac{f^{n}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f^{n+1}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt.$$

Next he wrote like the following:

If $m$ and $M$ are the minimum and maximum of $\frac{f^{n+1}(x)}{n!}$ on $[a, x]$, then $$m \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{n+1} = m\int_{a}^{x}(x-t)^ndt \leq \int_{a}^{x}\frac{f^{n+1}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt \leq M\int_{a}^{x}(x-t)^ndt = M \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$
So we can write $$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f^{n+1}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt = \alpha\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ for some number $\alpha$ between $m$ and $M$.

Next he wrote like the following:

Since we've assumed that $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous, this means that for some $t$ in $(a,x)$ we can also write $$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f^{n+1}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!} \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}.$$

I think it is obvious that for some $t \in [a, x]$, 
$$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f^{n+1}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}.$$

But I don't think it is obvious that for some $t \in (a, x)$, $$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f^{n+1}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}.$$

Why $t \in (a, x)$?

Comment: It would be useful if you tell us what he is trying to prove (I don't have the book). Is it possible that what he wants to prove is trivial if $t=a$ or $t=x$?

Comment: Michael Spivak derived the following result by integral by parts on p.423: If $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous on $[a, x]$, $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \cdots + f^{n}(a)/n! (x-a)^n + \int_{a}^{x} f^{n+1}(t)/n! (x-t)^n dt$. Then he says $\int_{a}^{x} f^{n+1}(t)/n! (x-t)^n = f^{(n+1)}(t)/(n+1)! (x-a)^{n+1}$ for some $t in (a, x)$.

Comment: Next, on p.424 he proved the following theorem: Suppose that $f', \cdots, f^{(n+1)}$ are defined on $[a, x]$, and that $R_{n,a}(x)$ is defined by $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + \cdots + f^{n}(a)/n! (x-a)^n + R_{n,a}(x)$. Then $R_{n,a}(x) = f^{(n+1)}(t)/(n+1)! (x-a)^{n+1}$ for some $t$ in $(a, x)$ (Lagrange form of the remainder).

Comment: After reading this theorem on p.424, it is obvious that we can choose $t$ from $(a, x)$. But when I was reading p.423, it was not obvious.